# mail() function not sending email to all

Tags: php, email

I have a database filled with ~400 email addresses; all these people were supposed to receive an email with some data unique to their account. I created a php script, which iterated through these email addresses. However, not all people received an email.

Is there any way I can do this better? You can find the script below.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Email WHERE 1;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $surname = $row['surname'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $ticket = $row['ticket_code'];

    $now = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

    $to      = $email;
    $subject = 'Your ticket code';
    $message = 'Hi,
    You were selected to be a part of our charity event. You can find your ticket code below. See you then!
    '.$ticket;
    $headers = 'From: our@email.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: our@email.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    $lqs = "UPDATE Email SET `email_send`='$now' WHERE `ticket_code`='$ticket'";
    $resulter = mysql_query($lqs);

}
```

Comment: In which case some people didn't receive the mail ? Only the X last ones ? Or it's random ?

Comment: Or it's maybe related to the domain name, like all the `@aol.com` for instance?

Comment: We kind of need need more info on this part. Is it just send out to one person? two persons. Not all is quite a vague statement. Can you be a bit more specific. Maybe they have a certain character in their name the php can't proces?

Comment: Try from local or try from hosted site?

Comment: BTW, you should be a bit more carefull regarding your mail header. It lacks a lot of information and it might eligible as spam on reception. [Check that](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?410825-Everything-i-send-goes-into-spam&highlight=spam) if you have a bit of time.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mark it as answered, but it helped a lot. Although some people (Gmail and Hotmail) still didn't get it, but I think that has something to do with it being treated as spam.

Comment: @User183849481 - No problem, I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you do not use the PHP mail() function. I found that it produced problems with certain email providers, such as Hotmail and GMAIL.

I would use the PHPMailer library - see Github link here https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Here's an example of how it works:

```
<?php

    require 'PHPMailer/_lib/class.phpmailer.php';

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Email");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->isMail();  // Set mailer to use Mail

    $mail->From = ''; // email sender
    $mail->FromName = ''; // name of sender
    $mail->AddAddress('', '');    // pass in the recipient email, and recipient name
    $mail->AddReplyTo('', ''); // reply email address, reply name

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;     // Set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->isHTML(true);      // Set email format to HTML

    // subject
    $mail->Subject = ""; // email subject

    //message
    $mail->Body    = "      

    <!doctype html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>


    </body>
    </html>

    ";

    // Send email to recipient

    if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

    $ticket = $row['ticket_code'];
    $now = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

    // update email table
    $update = mysql_query (" 
    UPDATE Email SET `email_send`='$now'
    WHERE `ticket_code`='$ticket' ");

    }


 ?>
```

Using this library and classes has worked well for me so far and seems to work without any exception with all email providers.